# Issue with Border or padding on html elements

Tags: html, css

Hey guys Im currently trying to get a textbox a select menu and a button all into one sized div cleanly but im running into an issue where each element has odd borders/margins which prevent it from rendering properly (the button appears below the text box and select menu)

Heres the html Im currently using

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="search-panel">
        <div class="search-panel-logo">
            <img src="img.png" class="search-panel-logo-img" />
        </div>

        <div class="search-panel-searchbar">
            <form class="search-panel-frm" action="" id="fsearchbar">
                <input class="search-panel-frm" type="text" id="tseachtext" name="tsearchtext" value="Search" />
                <select class="search-panel-frm" id="ssearchselect" name="ssearchselect">
                    <option value="Cars">Cars</option> 
                </select>
                <input class="search-panel-frm" type="button" id="bsearchgo" name="bsearchgo" value="Search!" />
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and heres the CSS:

```
.content {
    background:inherit;
    width:950px;
    height:600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.search-panel {
    width:inherit;
    height:500px;
    background:#093;
    margin:0 auto;

}
.search-panel-searchbar {
    width:inherit;
    height:30px;

}

.search-panel-searchbar-frm {
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;

}

.search-panel-searchbar-frm-text {
    width:60%;
    height:70%;

}

.search-panel-searchbar-frm-select {
    width:20%;
    height:80%;

}

.search-panel-searchbar-frm-go {
    width:20%;
    height:80%;

}
```

any idea what I can add to get all the elements to appear in one line as opposed to two, Ive already tried

```
border:0;
margin:0;
```

and it didnt fix the problem.

Comment: You are trying to put everything in one single row, right ?

Comment: Yes everything should appear in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal, some CSS tricks had to be applied, see below the CSS:

**CSS**

```
/* wrapper */
.search-panel-searchbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* form elements must be wrapped and not a direct child of the form tag */
.search-panel-searchbar > form > div {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height:30px;
}

/* input[type="text"] */
.search-panel-searchbar-frm-text {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    height: 16px;  /* necessary to fix height issue on windows browsers */
    padding: 6px 0;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color:#fff;
    width: 60%;
    text-indent: 4px;
    float: left;
}

/* select */
.search-panel-searchbar-frm-select {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 6px 4px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color:#fff;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    margin-left:-1px; /* pull to prevent border overflow issue with % */
}

/* input[type="button"] */
.search-panel-searchbar-frm-go {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 6px 0;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color:#fff;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:-1px; /* pull to prevent border overflow issue with % */
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**Note:**

CSS does not include style given on the Fiddle example to a visual demonstration, like the button hover and body background.

---

Please take note that unfortunately, each browser (and OS!) deals with the `select` in different ways, and it's likely that on one or two browsers, the style may differ.

The [working Fiddle example!](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/KZfjk/)

[image]

## Screen shot matches tests performed on:

**Linux Ubuntu 12.04**

- Firefox 12.0
- Chromium 18.0.1025.151 (Developer Build 130497 Linux)

**Windows XP Profissional versão 2002 Service Pack 3**

- Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702
- Opera 11.62
- Firefox 3.6.16
- Safari 5.1.2 <sup>(only select box height fail)</sup>
- Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m
- K-Meleon 1.5.4 <sup>(fail due to font-family)</sup>

**Windows 7 Home Edition Service Pack 1**

- Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.164211C
- Opera 11.62
- Firefox 12.0
- Safari 5.1.4
- Google Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m

The `font-family` that you will use must contain a font family declaration at the end to prevent line-height and text-size issues. e.g., `font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the whitespace between the elements.

Also, using `width: inherit` is probably not a good idea - try `width: 100%` instead or something along those lines. `height: inherit` can be replaced with `height: auto;` (or just omitted).

Comment: Tried adding 100% to all applicable areas to no avail

Comment: Might have missed something but Im doubting it

Answer (score 0):

1. You've posted some CSS classes that doesn't apply to the HTML you posted (eg. `.search-panel-searchbar-frm-go`)
2. You're applying the class search-panel-frm to your form element as well as elements within the form. Are you sure this is what you want?
3. I'm not seeing the same problem: The input, select and input:button all appear on the same line for me.

You can try adding this simple fix to keep everything on one line which may give you some ideas.

```
.search-panel-frm *
{
 white-space:nowrap;
}
```

If all your elements are already on the same line and you want them to line up better try different values for vertical-align, such as:

```
.search-panel-frm *
{
 vertical-align:top;
}
```